# Unable to Connect To NodeJS server Running on EC2 from NGINX on another EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

1. We are running a nodejs HTTP server on port 8090 on Amazon EC2 instance 1
2. We are running NGINX on port 80 at Amazon EC2 instance 2
3. In the NGINX we have configured upstream for our NodeJS Server
4. Now we are unable to get socket.io/socket.io.js from my machine using IP of the EC2 machine where NGINX is running.

Yes i have configured the inbout / outbound policy for port 8090

**NGINX IP**        :- 51.122.71.253 (sample IP)

**EC2 INSTANCE 1 IP** :- 5x.18x.8x.24x

**The Problem:**

I am unable to get http://51.122.71.253/socket.io/socket.io.js from my local machine via NGINX.

But i can access the file from EC2 instance 1 directly http://5x.18x.8x.24x:8090/socket.io/socket.io.js

Same setup with same NGINX.conf is working in our local LAN.
Is there any special trick with the EC2 for port 80?

**Configuration File**

```
http 
{
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade
    {
        default upgrade;
            '' close;
    }

        upstream node_server
        {
                ip_hash;   
                server 5x.18x.8x.24x:8090;
        }

     server
        {
                listen 80;

                location /
                {
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_read_timeout 3000;

                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                        proxy_pass http://node_server;
                        client_body_in_file_only clean;

                        client_body_buffer_size 32K;

                        client_max_body_size 400M;

                        sendfile on;
                        send_timeout 300s;
                }
        }
```

**What we are trying to achieve:-**

Actually on our client Side Network all the ports Except 80 is blocked , so we are trying NGINX as proxy to redirect socket connection from port 80 to our port 8090.

(Client Machine) -> (NGINX PROXY) -> (EC2 INSTANCE NODEJS SERVER RUNINNG @ 8090)

Comment: This is most likely a security group setting issue. Post your security group rules.

Comment: I don't think it has any security group issue. If i wget from inside the NGINX machine i can fetch the file using wget http://5x.18x.8x.24x:8090/socket.io/socket.io.js.  Also the settings is working fine with any other port except port 80. Also if any problem with the port 80 then i can't see the NGINX pages from my local machine

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. You have to change the port from 80 to any other port in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.

I have changed the port to 81.

```
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  localhost;
```

Then please restart the NGINX and it will work.